# Warning message: Error in cat("", list(Survived = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, : argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am trying to use a titanic csv for a project but when using `read.csv` this warning shows up. I am unsure how to continue or what it means.

I used:

```
titanic <-  read.csv("path from my device")
```

This resulted in the message:

> There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

which then gave me:

> Error in cat("", list(Survived = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,  :
> argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Comment: If [this](https://github.com/datasciencedojo/datasets/blob/master/titanic.csv) is the csv you are using, I cant recreate this error on my machine. Perhaps try restarting the R session/Rstudio, or perhaps the file has been altered. Other than that its difficult to help without more information on your data